# What does the variable $v$ in characteristic function of a random variable signify?

Tags: probability

The characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is given as:

$$E(e^{jvX}) = \int _{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{jvx} p(x) dx $$

This is interpreted as either mean of function $e^{jvx}$ or fourier transform of pdf $p(x)$. I know that $x$ represents random variable, but what does $v$ represents? What is its physical significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a heuristic (or "physical") interpretation consider the following "real version" of the characteristic function instead:
$$E_X(\omega):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(\omega x) p(x)\ dx\ .$$
Without the factor $\cos(\omega x)$ all values $x$ that the random variable $X$ can take are "equally important". Introducing this factor modulates this importance with frequency $\omega$. If it so happens that $X$ tends to prefer values which are spaced with period ${2\pi\over\omega_0}$ for some $\omega_0$ then this will show up in $|E_X(\omega_0)|$ becoming large.

In this way $\omega$ (the $v$ in your question) can be considered as a "sensor setting" chosen to investigate whether the given PDF $p$ has some inbuilt periodicity at frequency $\omega$. The Fourier inversion theorem guarantees that the collection of all sensor readings $E_X(\omega)$ $(\omega\in{\mathbb R})$ is sufficient to reproduce $p$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: It will take time to completely understand your answer. But thanks for the effort. Can you give any references or links. :)

Answer (score 0):

Having $X$ as a random variable you can define a new random process $Y(v)=e^{ivX}$, so you eventually find the mean of this random process.